# Else statement syntax error in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

Two points:

1. I am a beginner in *google app script* for spreadsheet.
2. I am getting a syntax error in my `else` statement

   ```
   function myFunction() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var tt = ss.getActiveCell(B12);
     var tpd = ss.getActiveCell(B13);

     If (tt.getValue() > 2798.88)
     {
         tpd.setValue((tt.getValue()*100)/118)
     } 
     else
     {
         tpd.setValue((tt.getValue()*100)112)
     }
   }
   ```

Can someone point out where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Try this?  `tpd.setValue((tt.getValue()*100)/112)`  (I added the division symbol `/`)

Answer (score 3):

your writing `If` this should be `if` with a lowercase **i**.

also as @Tim Randall told you forgetting the `/` division symbol in your expression